# How do I test if my Emacs is in minGW environment?

Tags: microsoft-windows

I have a elisp script that needs to work across different OS platform. So I need to use the `convert-standard-filename` to make sure the filename confirms to OS standard.

But I found Emacs for Windows can handle Windows filename correctly, and it somehow cannot handle the filename returned by the `convert-standard-filename`.

So I need a way to test if the script is executing in s `minGW` environment, and return the raw filename.

Comment: Within MSYS2, the environment variable `MSYSTEM` is usually set.  You could check against it with something like `(if (getenv "MSYSTEM") ...)`

Comment: My bad. I am using Emacs for Windows. I thought it relies on MSYS, but it not. I think it only depends on the `mingw` system.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `system-type`?

Comment: Within [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org), you could change the test to something like this `(if (string-match "MINGW" (getenv "MSYSTEM")) ...)`.  I can't say if works for [MinGW](http://mingw.org).

Comment: @ArashEsbati, no `minGW` does not set the `MSYSTEM` variable.

Comment: Emacs not handling a filename returned from its own `convert-standard-filename` sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using `system-type`

If you can roll out `cygwin` environment, then using `system-type` is a reliable way to test if Emacs is running in **minGW** or **MSYS** environment. If `system-type` is *windows-nt*, it must be one of the two.

## Alternatively

So far, I found using the `SHELL` variable in the Emacs environment is a reliable to to identify it it is running in **minGW** environment.

No matter in MSYS or mingGW environment, the `SHELL` variable is set to

```
/some/path/cmdproxy.exe
```

And I use the last part as a identifier.